# Потоки с параметрами c#

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Задание звучит следующим образом:

> Разработать программу для сравнения эффективности двух алгоритмов
>   сортировки путем их одновременного запуска на случайном массиве из 500
>   000 целых чисел (случайные числа генерировать в диапазоне от 0 до 1000
>   000). Для повышения точности сравнения проводить сортировку каждым из
>   алгоритмов не менее 10 раз. Результаты усреднять.

Проблема в том, что программа сортирует массив на первой итерации и дальше опять проходит уже по отсортированному. каким образом мне нужно исправить код, чтобы у меня после каждой итерации отсортированный массив замещался исходным для повторной сортировки? вот код:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr = new int[length];
        ArrayRandomizer(arr);
        int[] copyarr = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            copyarr[i] = arr[i];
        }

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(shellSort));
            t1.Start(arr);

            Thread t2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(BubbleSort));
            t2.Start(copyarr);

        Console.Read();

    }
    static int[] ArrayRandomizer(int[] Arr)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++) 
        {
            Arr[i] = rand.Next(0, 1000000);
        }
        return Arr;
    }

    static void shellSort(object ara)
    {
        int[] arr = (int[])ara;

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            double[] exectime = new double[10];
            double result=0;
            int index = -1;
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                int j;
                int step = arr.Length / 2;
                while (step > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < (arr.Length - step); i++)
                    {
                        j = i;
                        while ((j >= 0) && (arr[j] > arr[j + step]))
                        {
                            int tmp = arr[j];
                            arr[j] = arr[j + step];
                            arr[j + step] = tmp;
                            j -= step;
                        }
                    }
                    step = step / 2;
                }

                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("поток с сортировкой шелла: " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) + " миллисекунд");
                index++;
                exectime[index] = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                sw.Reset();
            }
            for (int n = 0; n < exectime.Length; n++) 
            {
                result += exectime[n];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Среднее время выполнения шелла: " + result / exectime.Length);

        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
    static void BubbleSort(object copyara)
   {
            int[] arr = (int[])copyara;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            double[] exectime = new double[10];
            double result = 0;
            int index = -1;
            for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - i - 1; j++)
                    {
                    if ((arr[j] > arr[j + 1]))
                        {
                            int temp = arr[j];
                            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                            arr[j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("поток с сортировкой пузырьком: " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) + " миллисекунд");
                index++;
                exectime[index] = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                sw.Reset();
            }
            for (int n = 0; n < exectime.Length; n++)
            {
                result += exectime[n];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Среднее время выполнения пузырька: " + result / exectime.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: По-моему, делать тест двух разных алгоритмов _одновременно_ неправильно: массивы по 500000 элементов не влезут в кэш-память процессора, а значит, данные будут подтягиваться из основной памяти в процессе работы. И два одновременно работающих потока будут мешать друг другу. То есть пропускная способность шины памяти может оказаться решающей. Так что тестируйте ваши алгоритмы последовательно.

Comment: Я бы изменил заголовок вопроса на "Сравнение сортировок по времени" или что-то подобное, для соответствия вопросу

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы использование массивов вообще не влияло на измерения, то на вход можно передать не один массив, а массив из 10 одинаковых массивов, что впрочем может потребовать лишней памяти.

Соответственно можно копировать массив перед каждым запуском, например Array.Copy() - его же лучше использовать и в начала вместо цикла. Исследование https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c гласит, то этот метод работает со скоростью копирования памяти. На время копирования массива Stopwatch можно выключать.

Answer (score 2):

Как альтернатива предложенному варианту, если вы ограничены по памяти, можно вспомнить, что `Random` не является настоящим ГСЧ и зависит от начального значения (seed). Если перед генерацией последовательности указать в конструкторе `new Random(seed)`, то последовательность будет генерироваться всегда одинаковая. Это работает медленнее чем копирование, но уменьшает расход памяти до одного массива на все исследуемые методы сортировки.

`StopWatch` включать строго перед вызовом исследуемого метода и выключать после его завершения.

Про особенности замеров времени почитайте тут, если еще не читали конечно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547742/198316

И забудьте про потоки если нужны нормальные измерения, они только в теории работают параллельно, на практике, они могут и будут мешать друг другу, особенно на долгих операциях с большими данными. Не смотря на количество ядер в современных процессорах, у них как минимум есть общий кэш 3-го уровня, который придется постоянно перечитывать переключаясь между потоками, и нет гарантии, что потоки будут работать на разных ядрах, они вполне могут быть запущены на одном ядре по усмотрению ОС.

Comment: Кстати, хорошая идея с `seed`.